# JS How to push integers from for loop into array

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, push

```
var period  = document.getElementById('period').value;
        var col = element.id.split('time')[1];
        var ValueArr=[];
        for(var x= 0;x < period; x++){
            var taskValue = document.getElementById('taskDone'+x).value;
            for(var p= 0;p < taskValue; p++){
                var ValueB = document.getElementById(col+"_"+taskValue).value;
                console.log(ValueB);
                ValueArr.push(ValueB);
                //var newValue = ValueArr.sort(function (a, b) {  return a - b;  });
            }
        }
        alert(newValue);
```

So I have this in a function and I want to push ValueB into ValueArr.
For ValueB it will be with unspecified length of numbers and with unspecified numbers but when I try I get This:https://i.stack.imgur.com/QqVpm.jpg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have done mistake in `alert`. It should be `alert(ValueArr);` instead of `alert(newValue);` . That is why you are getting that error `Reference error: newValue is not defined`. Also you need unique elements in `ValueArr`, so use this code

```
var newValue = ValueArr.filter(function(itm, i, a) {
    return i == a.indexOf(itm);
});
```

#### Fixed code:

```
var period  = document.getElementById('period').value;
var col = element.id.split('time')[1];
var ValueArr=[];
for(var x= 0;x < period; x++){
    var taskValue = document.getElementById('taskDone'+x).value;
    for(var p= 0;p < taskValue; p++){
        var ValueB = document.getElementById(col+"_"+taskValue).value;
        console.log(ValueB);
        ValueArr.push(ValueB);
        var newValue = ValueArr.filter(function(itm, i, a) {
             return i == a.indexOf(itm);
        });
        //var newValue = ValueArr.sort(function (a, b) {  return a - b;  });
    }
}
alert(ValueArr);
```

Comment: no, I am trying to fix the push if you see in the picture it prints what is in ValueArr after the push and I only want to have 1,2,3